# how to use html agility pack to extract all url from html text

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Often I extract file names from html text data using regex but I heard the html agility pack is good for parsing html data. how  can I use html agility pack to extract all url from html data. Can any one guide me with sample code. Thanks.

This is my code sample which works fine.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private ArrayList GetFilesName(string Source)
{
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=src=\")([^\"]+)(?=\")", 1);
    MatchCollection matchCollection = regex.Matches(Source);
    foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
    {
        if (!match.get_Value().StartsWith("http://"))
        {
                    arrayList.Add(Path.GetFileName(match.get_Value()));
                }
                match.NextMatch();
            }
            ArrayList arrayList1 = arrayList;
            return arrayList1;
        }

private string ReplaceSrc(string Source)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=src=\")([^\"]+)(?=\")", 1);
    MatchCollection matchCollection = regex.Matches(Source);
    foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
    {
        string value = match.get_Value();
        string str = string.Concat("images/", Path.GetFileName(value));
        Source = Source.Replace(value, str);
        match.NextMatch();
    }
    string source = Source;
    return source;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all `img` tags with non-empty `src` attribute (otherwise you will get *NullReferenceException* during getting attribute value):

```
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.Load(path_to_file);
var urls = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src!='']")
               .Select(i => i.Attributes["src"].Value);
```

Comment: this sample is bit friendly

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var images = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
    .Where(i => i.GetAttributeValue("src", null) != null)
    .Select(i => i.Attributes["src"].Value);
```

This selects all the `<img>` elements from the document which have `src` property set, and return these URLs.

Comment: Why not just `doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").Select(i => i.GetAttributeValue("src", null))`, With a `Where(url=>url!=null)` if you *must not* have nulls in your enumerable?